# Synchronize a replicas database thrjough an azure function

Tags: azure-functions, synchronization, azure-sql-database

i want to automate the process of the synchronization of replicas database. I found a way to automate the synchronization of processing of tables through an azure function and i want to do the same for the replicas database.
Does anybody knows how to do it ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what it actually is you're looking for. Are you aware of the [replication possibilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/replication-to-sql-database) provided by Azure?

Comment: More details needed to give you some directions or answers. what databases are you referring to. Note that Azure functions are not meant to do long running tasks, unless you want to use Azure Durable functions. Doing sync of table data, that is odd to attempt with Azure functions. Most of the on-prem and cloud DBs will have replication capabilities, that you must first look at rather than implementing your own.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [rickvdbosch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945525/rickvdbosch). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help the other community members.

You need to configure Azure SQL Database as the push subscriber in a one-way transactional or snapshot replication topology.

1. Create a transactional replication publication on a SQL Server database.
2. On SQL Server use the  **New Subscription Wizard**  or Transact-SQL statements to create a push to subscription to Azure SQL Database.
3. With single and pooled databases in Azure SQL Database, the initial data set is a snapshot that is created by the Snapshot Agent and distributed and applied by the Distribution Agent. With a SQL Managed Instance publisher, you can also use a database backup to seed the Azure SQL Database subscriber.
   For further information check [Replication of Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/replication-to-sql-database)